# Bootstrap - Using selector inside data-target that targets the first child

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m building a simple accordion type menu with bootstrap with this code:

```
<ul class="level_one">
    <li><a data-target=".level_2" data-toggle="collapse">Level One</a>
        <ul class="level_2 collapse">
             <li><a>Level 2</a></li>
             <li><a>Level 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
<ul class="level_one">
    <li><a data-target=".level_2" data-toggle="collapse">Level One</a>
        <ul class="level_2 collapse">
             <li><a>Level 2</a></li>
             <li><a>Level 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Althought this code works well, it triggers all elements that has the .level_2 class on it and I want to target only the nested element.
I have tried several CSS selectors inside the data-target attribute but none seems to get only the next element with that specific class.

I have seen a lot of examples that uses the ID to target the desired object but I can´t because this menu will be generated dinamically and for the sake of simplicity I don´t want to create random id names to make them work together neither use extra javascript since this functionallity already works well in bootstrap.

Extra info: There will be a lot of nesting in this menu, it´s not 2 level only menu.

Is there a specific CSS selector that can target the direct simbling that I could insert in the data-target attribute?

Comment: since you are generating the menu dynamically, my suggestion is to add something perhaps a `word` that is common to the parent and all the child menu.

Comment: In case there is no possible way to target the simbling element through the data-target attribute then I´ll consider that.

Comment: I think you should consider that. since it's a menu you need common elements like `ul `,`li`,`a` with common class name like  `.level_2`. it'll be hard to do identify. OR the other way is using jQuery

Comment: I think you might be able to achieve this using jQuery

Comment: Well I think I´ll go with adding a custom attribute to parent and child that relates them. I wish it could be simpler by just adding the correct CSS selector to the data-target attribute. No problem.